# flying star flash error message

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, syntax-error

I'm trying to make flying stars in flash. I decided to combine two tutorials I found (http://www.lashf.com/page/basic/running_circles_effect and http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/motion_guide_bc/), so I started first with this "running circles" tutorial. However, I got this error "Syntax error: expecting semicolon before leftbraces".

The code in question is

```
onClipEvent(enterFrame){

if(random(300) == 0) {

removeMovieClip(this)

};

};
```

I think the problem is because the actionscript from this tutorial is actionscript 2 while I'm working in actionscript 3. So how do I code it?

Comment: BTW, if you plan to code in AS3, you should not use AS2 tutorials at all, and find comparable AS3 tutorials. There are some available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `addEventListener()` to make your MC react on something that's happening in Flash. In order to perform actions on enter frame, add a listener to `Event.ENTER_FRAME`. The listener should be a named function that accepts one parameter of type `Event` or corresponding event type. [Learn more here.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29) Practically, wherever you see a `onClipEvent(*)` code, separate the code in brackets into a function, and use `addEventListener()` to attach a listener. Note, that in order to completely remove a MovieClip instance from anywhere, you should also remove attached event listeners, so write down what events does your MCs listen and use `removeEventListener()` where approppriate.

Comment: so in other words, the code should look more like this:   'addEventListener(listener:Event.ENTER_FRAME):void {} right?

Comment: `addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);`

`function onEnterFrame():void {}`

Comment: Wrote 'addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame); function onEnterFrame(); void {

if(random(300) == 0) {

removeMovieClip(this)

}

}' but still got some errors....

Comment: There's no `removeMovieClip()` function in AS3. The equivalent is `removeChild()` that should be targeted as `this.parent.removeChild(this);` [The manual on containers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html)

Comment: Like this? 'addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame); function onEnterFrame(); void {

if(random(300) == 0) {

this.parent.removeChild(this);

}

}
' I still got errors....

Comment: What errors do you get? Are they runtime or compile time? Please provide more data.

Comment: 1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before if.       1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before leftparen.
1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before this.  1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before dot.    1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightbrace.

Comment: Please update the question with current code. Syntax errors are not to be eliminated without complete view of code.

Comment: I found a new tutorial, this time with Actionscript 3.0. It's http://www.schoolofflash.com/2008/03/flash-cs3-particle-effect/comment-page-1/#comment-33402. I got the object to work although I still need to figure out how to make it fade out and shrink. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: A worthy tutorial. To shrink an object, play with its `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties, lower is smaller. To fade out, play with `alpha` property by slowly decreasing it, it's ranged from 0 to 1, and once it's at 0, drop the object. Also, see how that tutorial uses enter frame listeners. This is common practice, so get used to it.

Comment: should it be 'scaleXTo' and 'scaleYTo'? I wanted the object to become smaller as it moves away from the point.

Comment: No, it's not this easy. Flash won't autoscale object for you, unless you employ tweens, but this is a more complicated concept, so it's better if you will first manually employ scaling and alpha changing. The trick is, you add code to enter frame listener, which alters `scaleX`, `scaleY`, `alpha` properties, decreasing them as you see fit. These are numbers, so you can employ different iterative changes, either decrease by 0.01 or multiply by say 0.95. It's maths further. `this.scaleX-=0.01; this.scaleY-=0.01; this.alpha-=0.01; if (this.alpha<=0) // remove this object from stage`

Comment: like this?: `function animeStars(e:Event) 
{
 trace(this.starsArray);
 this.scaleX-=0.01;
 this.scaleY-=0.01;
 this.alpha-=0.01;
 if (this.alpha<=0) // remove this object from stage 
} myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addStars, animeStars);
`      except that it returns an error "expecting identifier before rightbrace"

Comment: What's `starsArray`? If it's an array of stars, as I expect, and you want to alter each star separately, you have to have a for loop for them stars, and apply property changing to each of the stars in turn. Also, `//` means that next text is a comment, I've put it there to signify a place where to put corresponding code. Also, `animeStars` is a function that should be used as an `Event.ENTER_FRAME` listener, as it processes already existing stars.

Comment: It's like particleArray from the tutorial. I just replaced 'Particle' with 'Stars'. YOu can download the tutorial and look at the code. That's what I did.